# Efficient CSS with child selectors, is it worth it?

Tags: css, optimization, css-selectors, micro-optimization, web-optimization

I know:

```
div > p
```

is faster to render than

```
div p
```

but, in the other hand, it occupies one more character, so it increase the time to send the CSS file.

I know the speed difference is very little, but if you have a very large CSS file with a lot of selectors it can start being important.

So, my question is: what is better, to lose some time rendering and do not use child selectors or use child selectors and lose some more time sending the CSS file?

Comment: Until you actually measure it and demonstrate that it is a noticeable hindrance to the user, why bother?

Comment: "if you have a very large CSS file with a lot of selectors it can start being important" Only for IE.

Comment: If you are this worried about bytes (I mean they're just a few **bytes**; as no-brainer as it sounds it takes **a thousand requests** of an extra byte to reach a single **kilo** byte), realize that `div>p` works just as well. No extra space characters.

Answer (score 2):

`Div > p` and `div p` are not the same

if you have the following structure:

```
<div>
  <p id="p1">first p</p>
  <section>
     <p id="p2">second p</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

`div > p` will apply to only p1, while `div p` to both p1 and p2.

The speed of the selectors will depend on your html structure.

Comment: But it is very important to consider. It's not fair to base something solely on performance if comparing two totally different things.

Comment: it's true but in some cases both do the same. then, you have to use one of them.

Comment: Then just pick one and move on.

Answer (score 1):

You should distinguish between loading the data from the server and parse the HTML+CSS.

at loading time you right (it will be slower)

but on render you are wrong (it will be faster)

P.S. don't forget: once you have the CSS - it won't be downloaded again.

Comment: ok. I hadn't thought about the cache. so, maybe it's better to use efficient CSS selectors despite it slows a bit the download.